# pyspark.sql.types.Row vs pyspark.sql.Row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Pyspark with Spark version 3.0.0 and when I try to get the type of a single row of a dataframe like:

```
type(df.collect()[1])
```

then I get it as

> pyspark.sql.types.Row

But looking at [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) I can't find this type, rather find [pyspark.sql.Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row) type. I guess both are same, if so what is the difference and why does it show as `pyspark.sql.types.Row` and not `pyspark.sql.Row`?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `Row` class source is located in the `pyspark.sql.types`. See the [sources](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html#Row).

Comment: If so then why is it mentioned to be a class inside `pyspark.sql` in documentation